# Possible to get reference to a View without setting the ContentView of an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-relativelayout, android-inflate

I want to be able to get reference to a `RelativeLayout` in the same way as

`RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);`

but without setting the `ContentView` of the `Activity`. I think it may have something to do with `Infalter`? My ultimate aim is to get this and add it as a child view of a custom view object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use LayoutInflater. Example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
View mv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
```

And then you could...

```
RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout)mv.findViewById(R.id.relative);
```